# -o in Linux terminal (Dash o); What does it mean?

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm new to the Linux terminal and a lot of commands use the `-o` option in them.

For example, to compile a [NASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler) program, you say

```
gcc prgram1.o -o prgram1
```

I can guess that it has something to do with output, but what is a proper definition and intuition for when it is used?

P.S.: I did a lot of googling and found a lot of pages with command references for Linux terminal, but nothing that covered the simple `-o`.

Comment: `man gcc` to access manual

Comment: THanks! How do I get back out of it?

Comment: Type `q` to exit a man page.

Comment: The program options to `gcc` are well documented: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html so please take time to read the documentation.

Comment: For the example, [direct link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-o) to documentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In most cases, *-o* will stand for output, but it's not a defined standard. It can potentially mean anything the developer wanted it to mean.

The only way someone can know which commands is to use a command line option of *--help*, *-h*, or something *-?* to display a simple list of commands. Again because the developer of the program chooses the possible input arguments and their meaning might differ from program to program.

The safest way to know is typically to run

```
man gcc
```

replacing the second part with the program name you want.

```
man <program name>
```

This lists a full guide for the program with a lot more detail and is usually well formatted to read on a terminal. Just press <kbd>Q</kbd> when you’re finished reading it.

Answer (score 8):

The *-o* flag is often used to denote the name of the output file. However, since it is a flag, you should look up in the manual what the specific flags are.

Also you might run a program with *-h* or *--help* to show a list of options and flags.

Answer (score 3):

The -o flag denotes the output file of a compile or link operation. Look at the man pages of the command to figure out all possible command line options.